# Type of expression is ambiguous without more context error fix requested

Tags: swift

So, I’m new to this. I was recently building an export file build on my iPad on swift playgrounds, and i came across this in @Environment(/.exportFiles)
In the error, the (/.exportFiles) is highlited. A fix to this would be highly appreciated

`

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport


struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.exportFiles) var exportAction
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Export Your file") {
            let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "symbols",
                                      withExtension: "json")!
            exportAction(moving: url)  {result in
                switch result {
                    case .success(let url):
                    print("Success! Moved to: /url")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You're using APIs from the iOS 14 beta that were replaced in the final release. That's why the environment value doesn't exist.

From the [iOS 14 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios-ipados-release-notes/ios-ipados-14-release-notes):

> The ImportFilesAction and ExportFilesAction APIs have been replaced
> with a collection of new view modifiers.
>
> Use the new .fileImporter() modifier to present a system interface for
> importing one or more files into your app, and the new .fileMover()
> modifier to move one or more existing files to a new location. The
> following is an example of a simple UI for importing and moving files:
>
> Use the new .fileExporter() modifier to present a system interface for
> exporting one or more documents from your app. In this example, an app
> provides a simple note-taking interface for quickly jotting down some
> text and then exporting it to disk:

```
struct FileMover : View {
    @Binding var selectedFiles: [URL]
    var includeDirectories: Bool = false
    
    @State private var isImporting: Bool = false
    @State private var isMovingSelection: Bool = false


    var body: some View {
        List(selectedFiles, id: \.self) { url in
            Text(url.absoluteString)
        }
        .toolbar {
            Button("Import", action: { isImporting = true })
            Button("Move", action: { isMovingSelection = true })
        }
        .fileImporter(
            isPresented: $isImporting,
            allowedContentTypes: includeDirectories ? [.item, .directory] : [.item],
            allowsMultipleSelection: true
        ) { result in
            do {
                selectedFiles = try result.get()
            } catch {
                // Handle failure.
            }
        }
        .fileMover(isPresented: $isMovingSelection, files: selectedFiles) {
            if case .success = $0 {
                selectedFiles = []
            } else {
                // Handle failure.
            }
        }
    }
}
```